# Select option in laravel not able to display values from database

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

Need your help, I have inserted value to database but when I edit the all values do not display. This is my code:

```
<?php 
$explode_values =  explode(",",@$checkpointvalues[$checkpoint['id']]['description']); ?>

{!! Form::select($checkpoint['id'].'_c[]', isset($error_messages[$checkpoint['id']])?$error_messages[$checkpoint['id']] : array(), $explode_values, array('multiple'=>'true', 'class'=>'form-control js-example-tags select2','id'=>$checkpoint['id'].'_c')) !!}
```

***`var_dump($explode_values);die;`:-***

```
array (size=4) 
0 => string 'blue' (length=4) 
1 => string 'green' (length=5) 
2 => string 'yellow' (length=6) 
3 => string 'zzzzzzzzzz' (length=10)
```

***but UI displayed only:-***

```
0 => string 'blue' (length=4) 
1 => string 'green' (length=5) 
2 => string 'yellow' (length=6)
```

Comment: var_dump($explode_values);die;
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'blue' (length=4)
  1 => string 'green' (length=5)
  2 => string 'yellow' (length=6)
  3 => string 'zzzzzzzzzz' (length=10)
but UI displayed only 
  0 => string 'blue' (length=4)
  1 => string 'green' (length=5)
  2 => string 'yellow' (length=6)

Comment: i think somewhere `$checkpoint['id']` is creating the problem,BTW i am not an expert of laravel. Can you able to print that too and show us?

Comment: it seems like id started from 1 while values started with index 0

Comment: I printed $checkpoint['id'] I got the result for

Comment: string '6e8a7bfc9b664ef3ad9812b7605e2304' (length=32)

Comment: how can I solve this?